# I cant splice elements in my 2d array - Java script

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, splice

I want to splice and replace element in my 2d array but keep getting this error.
admin.js:229 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'splice')
at xc (admin.js:229)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I want to replace or edit the name of a card stored in a 2d array with splice.

This is my code.

It works when I used number, but will throw error when I try to refrence the numbers with variables.

let gtIndex = arrMain.twoDIndexOf(renameMe.value)

let ccc = gtIndex.toNumber
let x =gtIndex[0];

let y = gtIndex[1];

arrMain[x].splice(y,1,renameMe.value)

Throws error when I click. Whats wrong with my code

You contribution will be well appreciated.

Comment: Is there  a better way of editing contents in a 2d array?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this SO (StackOverflow) post on how to format code blocks on SO. As it stands, your code format is difficult to read and not what you'll usually see on SO for code blocks: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks
You'll also want to include all the code referenced. Currently you reference arrMain but do not include the variable declaration line, among other things.